# Information not refreshing after updating it in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to set up modal using bootstrap for a project in which a client would be able to update their favorite team, city of birth and their size. Once the information is updated in the database I would like to update it in its respective field.

my modal code:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cityIn">You live in:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cityIn" placeholder="city">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="favoriteTeam">Favorite Team:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="favoriteTeam" placeholder="favoriteTeam">

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="size">Size:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="size" placeholder="size">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="usernameSubmitting" value="<?php echo $u; ?>">
                    </div>

                    <div class="alert alert-success" id="successAlert" role="alert" style="display: none"></div>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="updateFail" style="display:none"> </div>

                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveBtn" onClick="Changes()">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my script:

```
function Changes() {

    var updateCity = $("#cityIn").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "../php_parsers/update_parse.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            cityIn: $("#cityIn").val(),
            favoriteTeam: $("#favoriteTeam").val(),
            size: $("#size").val(),
            usernameSubmitting: $("#usernameSubmitting").val()

        }
    }).done(function(result) {
        if (result == "success") {
            $("#successAlert").html("Update successful").show();

        } else {
            $("#updateFail").html(result).show();
        }
    })

    $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $("#cityDisplayed").html(updateCity);
        $("#updateFail, #successAlert").hide();

    });
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you wanna update it? where is CityDisplayed??

Comment: your form doesnt seems to be connected to the script ?  do you want a solution to connect it ? because if u send the form data via ajax, your given information will remain in the form fields unless you reset them.

Comment: If you save the changes do you have the  success response?

Comment: @AshrafulIslamTushar it is connect on click btw

Comment: @Franco I do received a success response

Answer (score 0):

nvm my code was proper just forgot to save it.

```
function Changes() {

var updateCity = $("#cityIn").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "../php_parsers/update_parse.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        cityIn: $("#cityIn").val(),
        favoriteTeam: $("#favoriteTeam").val(),
        size: $("#size").val(),
        usernameSubmitting: $("#usernameSubmitting").val()

    }
}).done(function(result) {
    if (result == "success") {
        $("#successAlert").html("Update successful").show();

    } else {
        $("#updateFail").html(result).show();
    }
})

$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $("#cityDisplayed").html(updateCity);
    $("#updateFail, #successAlert").hide();

});
 }
```